# CORS allowed origins not applied using Spring MVC simple message broker

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-websocket

I'm using websockets with Spring & trying to configure CORS for my STOMP endpoint.  I have the following in my application-context.xml:

```
<mvc:cors>
    <mvc:mapping path="/notifier/**" allowed-origins="http://mydomain1.com,http://mydomain2.com" allowed-methods="GET, PUT" />
</mvc:cors>

<websocket:message-broker >
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/notifier" allowed-origins="http://mydomain1.com,http://mydomain2.com" >
        <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic"/>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

However, the subscription request fails on the client side due to the allowed origins being *.*, which the following CURL request confirms:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/notifier/info 
{"entropy":2116774357,"origins":["*:*"],"cookie_needed":true,"websocket":true}
```

The XML is the only means of configuration (no annotations or config in code).

Does anyone know why setting the allowed origins isn't working or whether there is anything I have left out?

Answer (score 0):

I tried configuration in xml but failed, and I use annotations.

add *.setAllowedOrigins("*")* in function **registerStompEndpoints**.

here is my code.

```
package config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.ChannelRegistration;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
    @Override
    public void configureClientOutboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.taskExecutor().corePoolSize(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.taskExecutor().corePoolSize(1);
    }
}
```

do not forget add package in <context:component-scan base-package="config" />